# jQuery Scroller animation

Tags: jquery, scroller

i am working on the parallax scroller and need a bit of help with the jquery animation.

```
if($(window).scrollTop() >= 180){
    $("#wasBorn").animate({"top": "+=20px"}, "fast");       }
```

as the page scrolls more than 180 the div is moving and how can i stop it at particular position let say `top:350px`

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $(window).scrollTop() >= 180
    && parseInt( $('#wasBorn').css('top') )<=330 ){
  $("#wasBorn").animate({"top": "+=20px"}, "fast");
}
```

This is not a perfect solution, though, as it the `#wasBorn` element may stop before 350px (if, for instance, it is triggered when the `top` value is 320, as, after the animation, it will be at 340 - less than the target 350, but greater than the test for 330). But, as I cannot see any more of how you are triggering this action, this is the best "from-the-hip" suggestion/solution I can come up with at the moment.

Alternately...

```
$wasBorn = $('#wasBorn');
....
if( $(window).scrollTop() >= 180 ){
  var curr = parseInt( $wasBorn.css('top') );
  if( curr<350 ){
    $wasBorn.animate(
      { top : Math.min( 350 , curr+20 ) } ,
      'fast'
    );
  }
}
```